# ADB automation HTTP data

Tags: android, adb

I am doing automated testing on one app. ***The idea is to automatize few steps (login for example) and also capture network traffic of each.***

I was able to do the automatization by using `input tap x y`

`adb shell input tap 500 1490`

After the command is ran, there is a network request triggered in the application. I want to get it logged somehow and see the request and response data.

I was looking into setting up the proxy on a computer and then monitoring the traffic there, but it won't work due to the apps security (SSL Pinning + others). Another thing I tried was checking the dump of all network logs. It could work but is not convenient as I cannot do it runtime (while running the automatization)

Is there some other way to do it through ADB or any other tool?

Comment: Does the app run on rooted devices? If yes [Frida](https://frida.re) might be worth a try. It could be used to modify the app at run-time if it has no anti-debugging protection. As it is only one app you can try to reverse it identify the SSL pinning and bypass it using Frida hooking.

Comment: @Robert it does run on rooted device yes. I've tried using Frida and injecting some packages in runtime to bypass SSL pinning but as soon as it gets modified, the app stops working properly (error on login)

Comment: Injecting packages may be a bit too much (may be you made a mistake on doing so?). I would just test a minor modification by hooking and logging one method. If that works try to hook the method that performs the comparison of the certificate digest for pinning. On a rooted device you can install your custom root CA as system CA so it should be accepted by the app (once you have defeated the pinning) unless it uses a complete custom set of root-CA certs.

Comment: @Robert Will give it a shot, after decompiling the code I found out its using this https://approov.io/ . So it might be a bit tricky